# startsWith() to check different letters or strings

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

Is there any way to check if a string starts with different letters instead of just one check.

Below is my current code :

```js
   myString.startsWith('M') ||
   myString.startsWith('L') ||
   myString.startsWith('V') ||
   myString.startsWith('H')
```

I want it to be minimized like below:

```js
   myString.startsWith('M'|| "L" || "V" || "H")
```

Any suggestions on usage of other methods or appropriate code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
/^[MLVH]/.test(myString)
```

It's faster and easier to read and maintain.

Comment: And if they aren't all single characters (though they are in the question): `/^(?:first|second|third|fourth)/`.

Comment: `It's faster` got any proof to back that claim?

Comment: @Nick Here's a proof: https://jsperf.com/check-first-letter/1 but to be honest with experience you don't need it (regex are fast)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression with a character set instead:

```js
const check = str => /^[MLVH]/.test(str);
console.log(check('Mmm'));
console.log(check('Lmm'));
console.log(check('mmm'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it that way:

```
['M','L','V','H'].some(chr => myStr.startsWith(chr));
```

In my opinion it's more simple and readble than regex.